# How to create a function that will apply on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Total noob here so any and all help would be so greatly appreciated. 
I need to create a function that will apply to pandas series (zipcode) on a DataFrame based on a conditional value on a different series (country) from the same DataFrame

The function I created

```
## function for retrieving only numeric characters
num_pattern = '(\d+)'

def numeric(x,y):
    try :
        a = re.search(x,y).group()
    except:
        a = None
    return a

df['zip'] = df['zip'].apply(lambda x: numeric(num_pattern,x))
```

I need this function to only be passed if the values in my `df['country']` column equals `'US'`

Comment: Do you really need the condition to be inside the function? Otherwise you can use `.loc` so your function will only  be applied to 'US'

Comment: this should do it: `df['zip'] = df.apply(lambda x: numeric(x.col_1), axis=1)`

Comment: @JuanC would you be able to share an example?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your post to include an example as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  For example, show us a sample 'before' DataFrame with 3 or 4 rows and 2 or 3 columns with `df = pd.DataFrame({....` Then, do it again by manually creating the result you want. (But, also, read the linked article and apply it to your question.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your apply on your df rows:

```
df['zip'] = df.apply(lambda x: numeric(num_pattern,x['zip']) if x['country']=='US' else x['zip'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting this error message IndexError: ('country', 'occurred at index email')

Comment: Even with the axis=1 parameter ?

Comment: wow im an idiot, it wouldve helped if i scrolled across. Thank you so very much!